# Postgresql: Filter array by series

Tags: arrays, postgresql, filter

Is there any way to filter and array column by a series?
It's simpler to explain with an example.
Imagine I have this data:

```
table: data
id   tag
1    {a,b,c,d}
2    {a,c,d,b}
3    {c,d,a,b}
4    {d,c,b,a}
5    {d,a,b,c}
6    {d,a,c,b}
```

Now I want to get all rows, which have ["a", "b"] in that order and no items in between:

`SELECT id from data where tags ???? ["a", "b"]`

That query should return: `1,3,5`

UPDATE 1:
After taking a look to `array_position` and `array_positionS`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-array.html

I wrote this query:

```
select id
from data 
where 'a' = ANY(tags)
    and 'b' = ANY(tags) 
    and (array_position(tags, 'a') + 1) = any(array_positions(tags, 'b' ))
```

Which works as expected

UPDATE 2:

As @klin comment, this would produce wrong result if 'a' can appear multiple times, for example `{a,a,b,c,d}`. So this is a more generic answer

```
select *
from data
where 'a' = any(tags)
and 'b' = any(tags) 
and (
    array_position(tags, 'a') + 1 = any(array_positions(tags, 'b' ))
    or array_position(tags, 'b') - 1 = any(array_positions(tags, 'a' )))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [a regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) on the text representation of the arrays.

```
select *
from my_table
where tag::text ~ '[\{,]a,b[,\}]'
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9fb97b2bbc4eec2d72c4bb59eb017bae)

Comment: thanks for the help. Take a look to the update, What query do you think would have better performance?

Comment: I came back to the question because your solution seemed too simple to me. Indeed, the query may give unexpected results in some cases: [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b75bddb0b8445b3abe45ac358735712b)

Comment: Hi @klin thanks for the extra effort. In deed you are right, I came to the same conclusion after some test's. However, the data I showed in the question is just an example. On the real data `a` can not be duplicate, while `b` can. I shoulded comment that on the original question.